# Azure Broker Service and SqlTableDependency

Tags: asp.net-mvc, azure, monitoring

I am trying to use SqlTableDependency in an MVC application, but I get the following error: 
`"Invalid object name 'sys.login_token'."`
The connection string used by `SqlTableDependency` is correct as I also use it for the entire application.

Comment: I have the same. Got a solution until now?

Comment: In order to work with SQL Broker in Azure you need to switch to Azure SQL Database Managed Instance because the classic Azure Databases don't offer that feature. Actually, that's pretty new stuff which Microsoft released recently. Take a look at this:
https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/sqlserverstorageengine/2018/03/07/what-is-azure-sql-database-managed-instance-2/ https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/blog/migrate-your-databases-to-a-fully-managed-service-with-azure-sql-database-managed-instance/

Answer (score 0):

To enable SQL SERVER Service Broker on Azure, you need to have a SQL Managed Instance Object instead of SQL Database on Azure. to more detail take a look at [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-sql/managed-instance/sql-managed-instance-paas-overview?view=azuresql) link.